# Float div to right with margin right at any screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have background image (size of image is 2600x1170)

```
sbBody {
    background: #999 url(footer_bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 1105px;
    font-family: Serif, Georgia, Times New Roman, Times;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I have a special area at this image (on right side of image), and I need to show special div that should be at this area, I did it with float right and margin

```
.main_box {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 505px;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
```

It looks fine in screen resolution 1900x1200, but if I change browser size my margin div is broke.
How I can have the same div position until browser window is more then 800px;

```
<body class="sbBody">
    <div class="main_box">
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: Typo in CSS, sbBody misses the class dot.

Comment: google for css media queries, and probably the main box needs a width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are floating your `div` to the right, you need to fix your background to top and right using :

```
background-position:top right;
```

Instead of `top center`

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fn6Zg/8/)**

CSS :

```
.sbBody {
    background: #999 url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-1280-720-10.jpg) right top no-repeat;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 1105px;
    font-family: Serif, Georgia, Times New Roman, Times;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.main_box {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 505px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    background:gold;

}
```

Comment: this is good point but effect is the same. problem in image size i think. But I can't change it

Comment: @a3code Could you create a fiddle with your issue so I can see what I can do.

Comment: You could always instead of setting a background set an image and then use media queries to resize and reposition that image. Then use z-index to position the layers, this unorthodox though and not recommended. You could also use JavaScript and run a function that returns the desired positioning